# Test importing a module executes a statement in pytest

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I want to test that importing a module will create a class instance. The code should look like that:

`mymodule.py`

```py
class Test:
    pass

Test()
```

But in pytest it seems impossible:

`test.py`

```py
def test(mocker):
    mocker.patch("mymodule.Test.__init__")
    import mymodule
    mymodule.Test.__init__.assert_called()
```

This doesn't work and I kind of get why. I patch before importing, then import overrides the patched version. But is there a way I can test it?

Don't ask me why... :) it's a 3rd party library that allows you to write your own plugins. Plugins are just modules that are imported, object creation must happen on import. Then, in `__init__` I do some initialization for this 3rd party lib.

Comment: You can't "patch before importing". In order to patch a module object, it has to be imported first inside the `patch` function, thus executing the module-level code. `import mymodule` is then basically a noop because the module is already imported after the `mocker.patch` line.

Comment: So my functionality is impossible to test?

Comment: I'd say not while `class Test` and `Test()` are in the same module. I may be wrong though.